# Css Grid layout with col width equal to max-content of all the content in the column

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I have certain number of divs with text inside them. The number of divs is unknown beforehand. I want to arrange the text in a grid such that each column width is equal to max-content of all the texts in that column.

```html
  <div class="container">
  <div class="item">Long text 01 </div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Align with 1</div>
  <div class="item">Align with 1 </div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  </div>
```

For this given dom, I want to satisfy following requirements.

1. If there is enough width and all items fit in a single row, each column width should equal to text width. i.e prefer horizontal layout if possible
2. If all the text can't fit in single row, and there are multiple rows, the width of each column is equal to max-content of all text in that column.
3. The texts in the column should start align with each other.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax( max-content, 0px));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 40px);
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px; 
}
```

I came up with this css but it only satisfies 1.

You can see the jsfiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/kg23qxup/160/

I am only successful in laying out the items horizontally with column width equal to max-content of items. It overflows the container and does not create second row.

I am positive grid is the right and easy way to go about this, but I could not seem to figure this out.

Comment: Because, you are using auto-fill columns so it can create as much as possible column. why you don't use flex layout, it best for your case

Comment: Oh I also want the items to align in the column. I think I forgot to mention that in the question.  If I use flex, the second row items might not align with the first row items. Unless you can do that using flex as well ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I completely used `grid` system and It seems impossible to realize the design which you want without `display flex`. Because grid `gaps` distort the display, but not like that in flex. Much smoother image is  can be created in Flex.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c d e f g"
                        
  }
  

.item {
  border:1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0 10px 15px 0;
}

.a{ 
grid-area:a;
background: green;
}

.b{ 
grid-area:b;
background:orange;
}

.c{ 
grid-area:c;
background:blue;
}

.d{ 
grid-area:d;
background:brown;

}

.e{ 
grid-area:e;
background:pink;
}

.f{ 
grid-area:f;
background:red;
}

.g{ 
grid-area:g;
background:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a item">Long text 01 </div>
  <div class="b item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="c item">Align with 1</div>
  <div class="d item">Align with 1 </div>
  <div class="e item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="f item">Item 6</div>
   <div class="g item">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="a item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="b item">Align with 1</div>
  <div class="c item">Align with 1 </div>
   <div class="d item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="e item">Item 6</div>
   <div class="f item">Item</div>
   <div class="g item">Item 2</div>
     </div>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="a item">Align with 1</div>
   <div class="b item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="c item">Item 6</div>
   <div class="d item">Item</div>
   <div class="e item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="f item">Align with 1</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks!! not quite what I was looking for. I don't want the items to take any more space than needed. For eg, in the example above, you could fit more items per row if they just occupy max-content. And also if one of the text is really long, it wraps. Ideally items would take max-content width and not wrap. (point 2).

Comment: Ok. Not at all. If I understood correctly, you want the columns to be shaped according to the content and to the bottom line. I edited my answer for you. You can check.

Comment: You are using grid-template-columns, grid-template rows in flex. That clearly does not work

Comment: Yes. I a little bit confused. I updated my answer. It is impossible to do such a thing without display flex anyway.